# How can i restore a Wordpress site with the DB and Wordpress Files

Tags: database, backup

Due to some circumstances i ended up with 2 folders and the task to restore a wordpress site.
One folder is called html and contains what i assume all the necessary files for the wordpress site (such as wp-admin, wp-content etc.)
https://i.imgur.com/IE3cevR.png

The other one is called database and contains what looks like the content of the "data" folder of a mysql installment.
https://i.imgur.com/tprbCyo.png

What i have tried is to restore the database so i can make a proper backup to load it into a new installation of wordpress as i assume that i than can just copy the other folder over and everything will run. For this i tried to copy the contents into the data folder of a fresh mysql install and start the service in hopes it would restore the db but unfortunatly the service doesn't start this way. Next i tried starting mysqld with the --innoDB-force-restore but this unfortunalty also ends in failure as this just crashes mysqld.
Is there any easy way i don't know of to restore the wordpress site or does anyone have any tips how i can succesfully restore the db?

Comment: This isn't really a Wordpress question as the main problem you have is how to restore a MySQL db from MySQL files, which may be a bit tricky. You'll probably get better responses by going to e.g. stackoverflow and asking how to restore a mysql from the files, not from a backup. Once you can login with the mysql client and look at the tables then you're good to go. (You'll find the credentials for the database in wp-config.php)

Comment: There are lots of questions like this on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

Comment: @mozboz thanks for the link. This is basicly what i have tried but i guess ill try it again in a linux enviroment. To keep it to wordpress, once i restored the db will i just have to copy over the files form the first folder into a fresh wordpress and everything will work as it should or do i have to do more steps to make it run again?

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone stumbles across the same problem, here is how i managed to restore my db.
I tried many different versions of mysql but all of them refused to start. The best i managed to do was to get it to start but with missing table contents by deleting the ibdata1 files.

Switching from windows to linux (since i knew the original db was running on a linux server i thought this might be worth a try) didn't help either.

In the end i tried to install MariaDB (since it supports all features of MySQL and adds some of its own) and it worked.

Here are the steps:

- Install MariaDB
- Start it by navigating your cmd console into the `bin` folder of the installation and starting it by typing `mariadbd.exe --console`.
- this will create the data structure. now you can close the cmd box
- move the contents of your old db into the data directory ( in my case `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.5\data)`
- now restart the service as mentioned above
- you should now be able to login and see your old db with all of it's data accesable

From here on i recommend making a proper backup using mysqldump.exe:

- again navigate a cmd into the bin folder (C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.5\bin)
- with this command you can create a sql file that you than can import into your wordpress server `mysqldump.exe --user=YourUserName --password=YourPassword --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="Pathdump.sql" --databases "DatabaseName"`